# Retrieve values within a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am new to java script. I have list to which I putting certain values into an array in JavaScript. What I am trying to do is to allow an user to select a value in an @Html.DropDownList, then find that id in the array and access the other other properties. The part I am having an issue with is retrieving these values from the array. The JavaScript is within the same page as drop down list. More detail can be provided if needed.

DropDownList

```
     @Html.DropDownList("StockCode", new SelectList(ViewBag.StockCodeList, "Value", "Text"),
     new
        {
            @class = "form-control selectpicker ",
            data_show_subtext = "true",
            data_live_search = "true",
            id = "StockCode",
            name = "StockCode"                                     
        })
```

Creating the array from a ViewBag(Which is a List), as a global var.

```
    <script>
    Stockarray = @Html.Raw(
        Json.Encode(
   ((List<GetProducts_Result>)ViewBag.AllStock).Select(stock => new
            {
                StockCode   =   stock.StockCode,
                Description = stock.Description,
                QtyInStock  =  stock.QtyInStock,
                QtyOnOrder  = stock.QtyOnOrder,
                QtyAllocated = stock.QtyAllocated,
                QtyLastStockTake = stock.QtyLastStockTake,
                StoredPrice = stock.StoredPrice,
            })
        )
    );

</script>
```

Below is where I am having the problem, in trying to get the correct values

```
<script>
    function FetchCall() {

        var SelectBox = $("#StockCode").val();

        var Values = selectWhere(Stockarray,'StockCode', SelectBox);


    for (var i=0; i<Values.length; i++)
    {
       var test = Values[i].value;  
       var param_value = i +'='+test;
    }

      alert(param_value.join(', '));
    }

    function selectWhere(data, propertyName, tofind) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i][propertyName] == tofind) return data[i];
        }
        return (null);
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to get the value of StockCode, Description, QtyInStock, QtyOnOrder etc.

Update I also have tried

Controler where GetStockItemsFromDB() returns a list of products

```
 ViewBag.Products = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetStockItemsFromDB().Take(2));
```

view

```
    var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Products))';
alert(model);
```

This allows me to see the contents but I can iterate of over them to get the values I neeed

Comment: SelectList(@ViewBag.StockCodeList... Do you have the @ in your actual code?

Comment: Yes but I have also tried escaping the razor to no success. I am at a loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution ended up with was. Not Using view bag and adding to my Model and few other changes.

Controller

```
AllProducts Products = new AllProducts();
Products.Products = new List<StockList>();
List<StockList> Stock = new List<StockList>();
Stock =  (from item in GetStockItemsFromDB()

    select new StockList()
    {
       Description = item.Description,
       QtyOnOrder = item.QtyOnOrder,
       StoredPrice = item.SalesPrice,
       StockCode = item.StockCode
     }).ToList();


Products.Products.AddRange(Stock);
Model.ProductsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Products);
```

View Sending in a hidden text box

```
<input type="hidden" id="param3" value="@Model.ProductsJson" />
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function FetchCall() {

        var SelectBox = $("#StockCode").val();

        var JSONStock = document.getElementById("param3").value;
        var parsed = JSON.parse(JSONStock);

        var tofind = SelectBox;

        var results = selectWhere(parsed, tofind)
        alert(results.StockCode + '    ' + results.Description);

        function selectWhere(parsed, tofind) {
            for (var i = 0; i < parsed.Products.length; i++) {
                if (parsed.Products[i].StockCode == tofind) {
                    return parsed.Products[i];
                }
            }
            return (null);
        }

    }
</script>
```